# Android: Open new Layout on Button Click and delete current one

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm currently trying to get familiar with Xamarin and therefore I created a little app. In this app I want to click on a button which opens a new Layout. But when I'm in the new layout and press the back button on my phone it goes back to the previous layout. I don't want that. Because I'm going to open several instances of the same layout but I don't want those instances to be saved in the history. Here is my code

```
public class AIVsPlayerActivity : Activity
{
    private int minValue = 0;
    private int maxValue = 100;
    private int valueToGuess;
    private int tries = 0;

    private bool hasWon = false;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set View
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AIVsPlayer);

        // Set value which has to be guessed
        var random = new Random();
        valueToGuess = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);

        // Create your application here

        TextView result = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.labResult);
        TextView labTries = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.labTries);
        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGuess);
        Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnNewRound);

        button1.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var guess = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tbGuess);
            int numberGuessed = int.Parse(guess.Text);

            if (numberGuessed > valueToGuess)
            {
                result.Text = "Your number is too high";
                tries++;
            }
            else if (numberGuessed < valueToGuess)
            {
                result.Text = "Your number is too low";
                tries++;
            }
            else if (numberGuessed == valueToGuess)
            {
                result.Text = "You made it! You've guessed my number!";
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} tries were needed", tries);
                hasWon = true;
            }
            labTries.Text = tries.ToString();

            if (hasWon)
            {
                button2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                button1.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
        };

        button2.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(AIVsPlayerActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };

    }
}
```

If the click event on button2 gets triggered I want to open the same layout just empty again with a new random number. I hope I could explain my problem.

Many thanks in advance

B. Pumpkin

Comment: Your answer helped me perfectly. I have to wait 6 minutes before I can mark it as correct somehow. I'll do it afterwards

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `Finish` on your current `Activity` after open the new one:

```
button2.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(AIVsPlayerActivity));
    StartActivity(intent);
    Finish();
};
```